Ubuntu 24.04 lts desktop
Curtin late commands is not working post installation os. Ubuntu 24.04 lts desktop
Post unattended installation os curtin commands not running by using autoimstal.yaml file

Based on the info in this question there are 2 things come to mind. 1. what are you asking? 2. What are curtin commands? Please update the question and add some details. it is clear there is more info you could provide.

This post may help... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490233/what-is-curtin-command-in-target-and-why-does-it-take-so-long-to-run?rq=1
